# Populating DataFrame from tuple with different size

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have data that is spread over the day.
I clustered it and then i calculated the ratio (weight) of each cluster per hour (not all the clusters exists in all hours).
(dataframe time_df )

```
   cluster                             Date
0       1 2014-02-28 14:24:59.535000+02:00
1       1 2014-02-28 14:26:35.019000+02:00
2       1 2014-02-28 14:27:37.213000+02:00
3       2 2014-02-28 14:28:35.246000+02:00
4       2 2014-02-28 14:29:37.283000+02:00
```

I group by hour and use np bincount to calculate the weight of each cluster:

```
group_by_hour = time_df.groupby(time_df.Date.dt.hour)
cluster_ids_hour = group_by_hour.cluster.\
    apply(lambda arr: list(range(0,(arr+1).max()+1)))
cluster_ratio_hour = group_by_hour.cluster.\
    apply(lambda arr: 1.0*np.bincount(arr+1)/len(arr))
```

This gives per hour a different array size of clusters and their weight 
It tried to construct a dataframe

pd.DataFrame(temp, columns=['hour','clusters','ratios'])

But I got the following:

```
   hour   clusters                                           weights
0    14        [0]                                            [1.0]
1    15     [0, 1]                 [0.488888888889, 0.511111111111]
2    16  [0, 1, 2]  [0.302325581395, 0.162790697674, 0.53488372093]
3    17  [0, 1, 2]                                  [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
4    18  [0, 1, 2]                                  [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
5    19  [0, 1, 2]                                  [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
6    20  [0, 1, 2]                                  [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
7    21  [0, 1, 2]                                  [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
8    22  [0, 1, 2]                                  [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
9    23  [0, 1, 2]                                  [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

How can I make it to have the cluster as index and hours as columns?

```
    0    1    2    3    4    ...
0    0.2    0.6    0.4    0.0    0.6
1    0.0    0.4    0.1    0.0    0.4
2    0.8    0.0    0.5    1.0    0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

time_df = pd.DataFrame({'cluster': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 2}, 
                        'Date': {0: pd.Timestamp('2014-02-28 12:24:59.535000'),
                                 1: pd.Timestamp('2014-02-28 12:26:35.019000'), 
                                 2: pd.Timestamp('2014-02-28 12:27:37.213000'), 
                                 3: pd.Timestamp('2014-02-28 12:28:35.246000'), 
                                 4: pd.Timestamp('2014-02-28 12:29:37.283000'), 
                                 5: pd.Timestamp('2014-02-28 13:27:37.213000'), 
                                 6: pd.Timestamp('2014-02-28 14:28:35.246000'), 
                                 7: pd.Timestamp('2014-02-28 14:29:37.283000')}})

print (time_df)
                     Date  cluster
0 2014-02-28 12:24:59.535        1
1 2014-02-28 12:26:35.019        1
2 2014-02-28 12:27:37.213        1
3 2014-02-28 12:28:35.246        2
4 2014-02-28 12:29:37.283        2
5 2014-02-28 13:27:37.213        1
6 2014-02-28 14:28:35.246        1
7 2014-02-28 14:29:37.283        2
```

```
group_by_hour = time_df.groupby(time_df.Date.dt.hour)
cluster_ids_hour = group_by_hour.cluster.\
    apply(lambda arr: list(range(0,(arr+1).max()+1)))
cluster_ratio_hour = group_by_hour.cluster.\
    apply(lambda arr: 1.0*np.bincount(arr+1)/len(arr))

print (cluster_ids_hour)
Date
12    [0, 1, 2, 3]
13       [0, 1, 2]
14    [0, 1, 2, 3]
Name: cluster, dtype: object

print (cluster_ratio_hour)
Date
12    [0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0.4]
13         [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
14    [0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5]
Name: cluster, dtype: object

#create DataFrames from both columns and concate them
df1 = pd.DataFrame(cluster_ids_hour.values.tolist(), index=cluster_ids_hour.index)
#print (df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(cluster_ratio_hour.values.tolist(), index=cluster_ratio_hour.index)
#print (df2)
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=('clusters','weights'))
print (df)
     clusters            weights               
            0  1  2    3       0    1    2    3
Date                                           
12          0  1  2  3.0     0.0  0.0  0.6  0.4
13          0  1  2  NaN     0.0  0.0  1.0  NaN
14          0  1  2  3.0     0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5
```

```
#reshape, cast clusters column to integer    
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
df['clusters'] = df['clusters'].astype(int)
#pivoting, fill NaN by 0
df = df.pivot(index='clusters', columns='Date', values='weights').fillna(0)

df.index.name = None
df.columns.name = None
print (df)
    12   13   14
0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.6  1.0  0.5
3  0.4  0.0  0.5
```

Comment: I wonder, this methods gives the cluster weight for a single day. I will run it for several days and then combine them all.
In some days i have only part of the hours (e.g. 12,13,14) while other will include all the hours,
How can i concat dataframe with different number of columns?

Comment: Sorry, i am not sure if i understand you. Do you need [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#set-logic-on-the-other-axes) function?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

time_df = pd.DataFrame({'cluster': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 2}, 
                        'Date': {0: pd.Timestamp('2014-02-28 12:24:59.535000'),
                                 1: pd.Timestamp('2014-02-28 12:26:35.019000'), 
                                 2: pd.Timestamp('2014-02-28 12:27:37.213000'), 
                                 3: pd.Timestamp('2014-02-28 12:28:35.246000'), 
                                 4: pd.Timestamp('2014-02-28 12:29:37.283000'), 
                                 5: pd.Timestamp('2014-02-28 13:27:37.213000'), 
                                 6: pd.Timestamp('2014-02-28 14:28:35.246000'), 
                                 7: pd.Timestamp('2014-02-28 14:29:37.283000')}})

print (time_df)
time_df_group = time_df.groupby([time_df.Date.dt.hour,time_df.cluster]).size()
cluster_hour_df =  time_df_group.unstack(level=0)
cluster_hour_df = cluster_hour_df[cluster_hour_df.columns.values].apply(lambda row: row / row.sum(), axis=0)
cluster_hour_df


Date    12  13  14
cluster         
1   0.6 1.0 0.5
2   0.4 NaN 0.5
```